# How does Hi-Fi Rush's ranking persistence work?

Tags: hi-fi-rush

I'm replaying levels after finishing the game and the ranking screen for each stage has the following information:

1. The overall ranks for each verse
2. The stars on each verse indicating whether Chai took damage
3. The SPECTRE rank and optional star for that level, if applicable
4. The scores for each verse

How does the rank information persist between playthroughs? For example, if I play the level twice and get different combinations of A and S ranks with different stars and score rankings, how does the game decide which aspects of the score carry between playthroughs as I try to get S ranks and stars on every grade?